# Content script for iframe inside extension popup or background script

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to interact with an iframe located in a chrome-extension popup. I know content.js can be injected in all frame using the manifest.json but it's working with frame inside a webpage and not inside the extension's popup.

Is it doable ? I tried many things but I didn't find a solution yet.

my manifest :

```
{
"name" :"test",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description" :"Scraping Facebook",
"permissions": [
  "cookies",
  "background",
  "tabs",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*",
  "storage",
  "unlimitedStorage"
],
"icons": { "128": "images/pint.png" },
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "js": ["jquery-3.1.0.min.js","content.js"],
    "run_at":"document_end"
  }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "styles/*",
    "fonts/*"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
"browser_action" :
    {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, I added my manifest.json

Comment: Are you trying to inject the content script into an iframe within the popup for your own extension or some other extension? It is implied that it is your own by the existence of a *popup.html* in your `browser_action`, but not explicitly stated.

Comment: Please [edit] to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] duplicating the problem. Usually, include a *manifest.json*, some of the background, content, and popup scripts and HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: It's the popup of my own extension and the iframe in it is from a different domain.

Comment: I ll edit the question with the files and more details

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `"all_frames": true` in your content script declaration to inject it into an iframe:

```js
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "http://example.com/*" ],
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "all_frames": true
}],
```

To differentiate this iframe from normal tabs you can add a dummy parameter to the URL when you create the iframe e.g. `http://example.com/?foo` so you can match it in manifest.json like `"http://example.com/*foo*"` for example.

Then you can use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging): the content script initiates it, and the extension script registers a listener.

- Trivial one-time sendMessage:

  content.js:

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('test', response => {
    console.log(response);
  });
  ```

  popup.js (or background.js and so on):

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log('popup got', msg, 'from', sender);
    sendResponse('response');
  });
  ```
- Long-lived port:

  content.js:

  ```js
  let port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'test'});
  port.onMessage.addListener((msg, port) => {
    console.log(msg);
  });
  port.postMessage('from-iframe');
  ```

  popup.js (or background.js and so on):

  ```js
  let iframePort; // in case you want to alter its behavior later in another function
  chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
    iframePort = port;
    port.onMessage.addListener((msg, port) => {
      console.log(msg);
    });
    port.postMessage('from-popup');
  });
  ```

An example of popup.html is really straightforward:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe width="500" height="500" src="http://example.com"></iframe>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course you can also add the iframe(s) programmatically using DOM manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer