# Run JS on iframe chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a simple chrome extension to load a page I do not have access to the code to in a pop up window.

The site however does not have an API to get the content I want. So I have loaded the page in an iFrame and attempting to use JS to strip out the content I do not want in the iFrame.

Manifest.JSON:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Website Ext",
  "description": "My Description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

Popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My extension</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
      }
      #status {
        /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
        white-space: pre;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 600px;
        height; 800px

      }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="status">
        <iframe src="http://domain.com" width="590px" height="795px">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Popup.JS:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("headerbody").remove();
document.getElementById("footerbody").remove();
document.getElementById("breadcrumb").remove();
document.getElementById("pagetitle").remove();
document.getElementById("actionbar").remove();
```

However the JS seems to be ignored any advice on how to get this to work would be appreciated.

I have tested the JS in chrome developer tools and it strips what I want it too.

Comment: you are attempting cross domain manipulation. i doubt its allowed. use a content script to modify the contents, with allframes true.

Comment: example: [content.js in iframe from chrome-extension popup](//stackoverflow.com/a/39901725)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [content.js in iframe from chrome-extension popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901128/content-js-in-iframe-from-chrome-extension-popup)