# Impossible to load an iframe inside the background page (status=canceled)

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension

I want to dynamicaly inject and load an iframe inside the background page. But every time, the request is canceled.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISTH7.png

That used to work a week ago. I don't know where I'm wrong.

To reproduce this issue, I created a small extension :

*manifest.js :*

```json
{
    "name": "iframe background",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "iframe"
    },

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

*background.js :*

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.src = 'http://localhost:3000/';
    iframe.onload = function() {
        console.log(iframe.contentDocument); // return null
    };
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

The page to load is not blocked by X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN.

I tried to put the iframe directly within a HTML background page with no luck.

I also tried to add an content_security_policy : 
`"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; frame-src 'self' http://localhost:3000/"`

But the iframe still doesn't load.

Does someone has a workaround or a solution to this problem?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome 58.0.3014.0 [enables Site Isolation for extensions by default](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d81f57c5700ed617cc183847ad3e0f35df1c8221) that makes the iframe load in a different renderer process handled by a separate chrome.exe OS process.

The 'canceled' message means that the extension's chrome.exe process canceled the request and it was handled by a different hidden chrome.exe process.

The correct approach is to declare a content script that will automatically run on the iframe URL and communicate to the background page. Note: only JSON-fiable data may be passed, in other words, you can pass innerHTML but not DOM elements. This is easy to handle though via DOMParser.

manifest.json additions:

```js
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://localhost:3000/*"],
    "js": ["iframe.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
}],
```

iframe.js:

```js
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();
// send something immediately
port.postMessage({html: document.documentElement.innerHTML});

// process any further messages from the background page
port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
    ..............
    // reply
    port.postMessage(anyJSONfiableObject); // not DOM elements!
});
```

background.js:

```js
var iframePort;

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
        '<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/"></iframe>');
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
    // save in a global variable to access it later from other functions
    iframePort = port;

    port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
        if (msg.html) {
            const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(msg.html, 'text/html');
            console.log(doc);
            alert('Received HTML from the iframe, see the console');
        }
    });
});
```

See also a similar QA: [content.js in iframe from chrome-extension popup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725/)

Comment: Is there any simple way to use https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage in Chrome extensions? cross-storage implicitly creates `<iframe src="http://example.com/hub">` and provides API to write data to `<iframe>`'s localStorage.

Comment: cross-storage seems to be working out of the box despite its `<iframe>` being red and `(cancelled)` in Network tab.

Comment: Why would you need a library for the functionality that can be implemented with just a few lines of code added to the template shown in this answer? Also, I have no idea is there any way to use that lib because I haven't tried it.

Comment: One drawback of your solution would be that the content script would be injected not only in `<iframe>` inside background page but in all tabs and iframes with the same url (e.g. http://example.com/hub).

Comment: Indeed. You can check `if (window != top)` and proceed only if that's the case.

Comment: Or you can specify an additional URL parameter when using it for an iframe and add [include_globs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for the content script declaration.