# background.js is no longer accessible after iframe is loaded in background.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In `background.js`, I injected an `iframe`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.action == "doubanSearch")
            test(request.title, request.year);
    }
);

function test(title, year){
    var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
    frame.src = 'https://movie.douban.com/subject_search?cat=1002&search_text=' + title + ' '+ year;
    document.body.appendChild(frame);
  }
```

However, once the `iframe` is loaded, the `background.js` no longer responds to `doubanSearch` request. Is there a solution to allow `background.js` remain responsive to future requests even `iframe` is loaded?

I have checked the `content.js` separately and can confirm it does what I want it to be doing.

## update 1

The `netflixContent.js` that makes requests:

```
var prevDOM = null;    
var prevMovieTitle = 'prevMovie';

// Mouse listener for any move event on the current document.
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var srcElement = e.srcElement; 
    if (srcElement == null)
        return;

    if (prevDOM != srcElement){
        prevDOM = srcElement;    
        return;    
    }       

    // find the bob-overlay class    
    if (srcElement.parentElement != null && srcElement.parentElement.className.startsWith('bob')) {    
        while (srcElement.className!="bob-overlay"){    
            srcElement = srcElement.parentElement;    
            // if srcElement is no longer a bob- class, we are out of luck here.    
            if (srcElement == null || !srcElement.className.startsWith('bob'))    
                return;    
        }    
    }     
        
    // the srcElement at this stage has to be bob-overlay class!   
    if (srcElement == null || srcElement.className!="bob-overlay")    
        return;        

    // now we are in the right place, get movie title and publication year    
    var movieTitle = srcElement.getElementsByClassName('bob-title');    
    var movieYear = srcElement.getElementsByClassName('year');            

    if (movieTitle.length != 1){    
        console.log('Movie title not found.', srcElement);    
        return;    
    }

    if (movieYear.length != 1){    
        console.log('Movie year not found.', srcElement);    
        return;    
    }        

    // now get the title and year    
    movieTitle = movieTitle[0].textContent;    
    movieYear = movieYear[0].textContent.trim();
        
    // if the current movie is the same as the previous movie, we return.    
    if (movieTitle == prevMovieTitle)    
        return;

    // return if title is empty    
    if (movieTitle == '')    
        return;

    // if movie year isn't empty, add parenthesis.    
    if (movieYear != '')   
        movieYear = '(' + movieYear + ')';        

    prevMovieTitle = movieTitle;    
    console.log('Movie found:', movieTitle, movieYear);

    // replace special characters with space.    
    movieTitle = movieTitle.replace(/[^\w\s]/g, ' ').trim();    
    console.log('Movie found (special characters removed) :', movieTitle, movieYear);
        
    // now let's send the message and start searching!    
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: 'doubanSearch', title: movieTitle, year: movieYear});                

}, false);
```

It is opensource hosted on [github](https://github.com/tmxkn1/RateMeNetflix) in case you need to check out the entire code. I'm really new to js and chrome extension development, so please execuse me for crappy coding :).

## update 2

The background page before a request is sent:

[image: before request is sent]

The background page after a request is sent and iframe is loaded

[image: after request is sent and iframe is loaded]

Also, the background page link is no longer available from the chrome://extensions:

[image]

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you, I've updated the question with the code making requests. I've tried debugging the request code and it does well by which I mean it continue to send requests. The background.js disappears when the `iframe` is loaded and shows the `iframe` source code and content.js instead.

Comment: Show a screenshot.

Comment: @wOxxOm screenshots added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site performs *frame-busting* (assigning `top.location` to an URL of the page itself) which navigates the background page to the site URL so the extension no longer has a background page. It looks like an oversight in Chrome which has been intermittently prevented in some recent versions and is about to be fixed for good in v67.

The solution is to sandbox the iframe by adding the following attribute:

```
frame.sandbox = 'allow-scripts';
```

Some sites may require more features to be allowed e.g. `allow-forms`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for the full list.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add the argument `allow-same-origin` otherwise it complains and won't load the page. Now I have a new problem. I can't seem to get the contents in `iframe`. what permission should I give to the `content.js`? The iframe source url does not work.

Comment: Make sure your content script declaration has `"all_frames": true` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725)) otherwise I don't know what you do to `get the contents`.