# Overwritten headers do not work for iframes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

For a very specifiy task I need to get the contents of an `iframe` with a different domain. The frame points to a foreign domain for which I cannot control the headers.

So I came up with a chrome extension to bypass the origin-policy of the foreign domain. Here is the extension:

`manifest.json:`

```
{
  ...

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

`background.js:`

```
var strip = [
  "content-security-policy",
  "x-frame-options",
  "access-control-allow-origin",
  "x-content-type-options"
];

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function(details) {
    var headers = details.responseHeaders.filter(function(header) {
      return strip.indexOf(header.name.toLowerCase()) < 0;
    });
    headers.push({
      name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      value: "*"
    });

    return {
      responseHeaders: headers
    };
  },
  {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
    /* types: [  // default: all types
      "main_frame",
      "sub_frame",
      "stylesheet",
      "script",
      "image",
      "object",
      "xmlhttprequest",
      "other"
    ] */
  },
  ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

---

With the extension I am able to frame pages which were otherwise not allowed to display inside a frame. But on the other hand, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` does not take effect on iframes at all. If I run `$('iframe').contents();` with the extension, I still get

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://my.domain" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at contents (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js:3199:25)
    at Function.map (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js:451:13)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js:3213:24)
    at <anonymous>:1:16`

Is this a bug?

Comment: AFAIK that's just how it is in the modern browsers and you can't directly access iframes with different origin. You can use a content script that runs inside that iframe, gets its data, and posts it in a message to the background page ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901128/content-js-in-iframe-from-chrome-extension-popup/39901725?s=3|44.5951#39901725)).

Comment: But it says it’s blocking it because of the origin?

Comment: I don't see that as a contradiction. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not related to cross-origin DOM access.

Comment: Could you maybe change the origin headers somehow?

Comment: It might be possible using a MitM proxy like WireShark, Proxomitron, Fiddler.

Comment: Creative idea, but it does not work in my usecase. Thanks for shedding some light on this topic for me