# Using document.querySelectorAll() in page loaded with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome plugin that uses a `content_scripts` manifest section to have a javascript file loaded every time a user visits some page.

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "css": ["styles.css"],
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www.coolsite.com/*"]
  }]
```

Inside the content.js I am making an HTTP call and in a result I receive an html page. I would like to parse that loaded html page with `document.querySelector()`, but this page is only available as a string. What's the best way to parse it?

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (ev) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            // parse xhr.responseText as DOM???
        }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "https://www.coolsite.com/store/" + shopName);
    xhr.send();
```

Comment: See examples for DOMParser or use xhr.responseType='document'

Comment: yeah thanks, responseType works. However this is a dynamic page, so I guess I need to load it into an iframe or webview first? What are the best practices?

Comment: Extensions can't use webview so iframe that is. Usually inside the background page ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725)).