# Usage of background.js to communicate with some external website and then execute content.js on that Website

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm building a chrome extension which basically uses `background.js` to communicate with **some external website**, and **after connecting** to it I need to run a `content.js` on it to get some data, maybe an image from it.

But as far as I know `content.js` are for current tabs only, but I'm trying to get something from that website for which I need a `content.js`, but this whole process is taking place in the background.

So I'm basically confused how to connect with the external website in the background and run a `content.js` on it at the same time.

I'll really appreciate any suggestions and ideas on this.

Comment: Case 1: if that URL returns everything you need in response HTML, just use XHR/fetch + DOMParser. Case 2: if that's a dynamic site, run it inside an iframe in your background page, see [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll work with your suggested methods. :-)

Comment: Content.js is injected into every tab a user opens. You can programmatically open a tab from the background.js to that URL if needed. As for the connecting it all together. Just use messaging between background <> content & background <> webpage.