# Use Facebook messages API/SDK in chrome extension?

Tags: facebook, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create a simple and fast Google Chrome extension for facebook messaging(it will be much more convinient than opening FB page just to check unread messages). I've spent many hours trying to find a way to retrieve the messages in the extension, however unsuccessfully(everything about this topic is outdated).

An option would be the extention to make ajax requests to a server of mine, which retrieves the FB messages via PHP I guess?

Other than that, is there a way to login in facebook and retrieve the last conversations via Chrome extension?

Comment: There is no access to user-to-user messages at all any more via API.

Comment: Extensions can open a minimized window (or a pinned inactive tab) with facebook URL, run a content script there and get the messages from DOM. Alternatively, make an [iframe inside background script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725) and webRequest API to [strip X-Frame-Options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15534822).