# How to get element in iframe which is created by background script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have create an iframe in my background script. But I have no idea how to get the element in the iframe. By the way, the extension has the permission to access the web server.

```js
let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("id", "iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "url_to_myWebServer");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

console.log(iframe); // iframe is shown
console.log(iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("pid")); // null
```

Comment: The background can't access a cross-origin iframe's contents. Use a content script as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725).

Comment: The issue is solved. Thank you.