# Is is possible to have fetch wait for a redirect?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch

I'm currently working on dynamically scraping a webpage from a web extension and am using the following code:

```
let url = "https://lykdat.com/search-result/?image_url=https://anf.scene7.com/is/image/anf/KIC_330-2455-0904-476_prod1?$product-hol-v1$&wid=800&hei=1000";

fetch(url,{redirect: 'follow'}).then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
  el.innerHTML = result;
  // console.log(typeof(tempPage));
  console.log(el);
  tempImgs = el.getElementsByTagName('img');
  console.log(tempImgs);
})
```

I want to be able to change any text that comes after the "image_url=" in order to change which image is being plugged into the website. Unfortunately, the page that I am trying to pull information from comes after a brief loading period so using the "fetch" function only pulls information from the loading screen, and not the actual page that I want. The redirect is not instantaneous and can take anywhere between 3-30 seconds and **I was wondering if there was any way to force fetch to wait for that redirect before scraping data.** Thanks so much for any help you can offer!

Comment: Although, I don't know about JavaScript for this, myself, I would use PHP's [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Look into loadHTMLFile, like `$dom = new DOMDocument; $dom->loadHTMLFile($urlHere); $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img'); foreach($imgs as $img){ $src = $img->getAttribute('src'); /* $src is src attribute of each image in loop */ }`.

Comment: The page is using a script to redirect to the final results so they won't be present in the initial HTML response no matter how long you wait - this is because `fetch` doesn't run scripts. You need to embed that site inside an iframe, declare a content script with `"all_frames":true` and a matching URL pattern so it'll run in that iframe, then communicate the results back via messaging ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725)).

Answer (score -1):

Use `await`, you need your function to be an async one for this to work.

```
async function YourFunctionName (){
  let url = "https://lykdat.com/search-result/?image_url=https://anf.scene7.com/is/image/anf/KIC_330-2455-0904-476_prod1?$product-hol-v1$&wid=800&hei=1000";

  var promise = await fetch(url,{redirect: 'follow'}).then(r => r.text()).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
  el.innerHTML = result;
  // console.log(typeof(tempPage));
  console.log(el);
  tempImgs = el.getElementsByTagName('img');
  console.log(tempImgs);
})
}

YourFunctionName();
```

Comment: For some reason, this solution still isn't working for me with the specific webpage I'm requesting. I believe it's because the page can be fully loaded, which satisfies the conditions of the await function, but work is still being done on a cloud computer. I believe this is why the loading page is still being pulled with this code. Do you have any idea of how to force the code to wait for redirect or is the code malfunctioning for some other reason? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The original code was already correctly using Promise API so this answer is completely off the mark.

Comment: As @wOxxOm says, the `.then()` in the OP's code implies waiting for the promise to resolve, so the `await` a) is redundant, b) creates a weird mixing of sytaxes, and c) is probably incorrect because I would guess it applies to the entire expression which follows it, not just the `fetch()` call.