# Remote loading iframe in chrome extension can't access chrome properties

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api

I am building a chrome extension which uses a back end (php) app with gmail API and because
i do not want to separate Google apps / i need to have the chrome extension consume a
backed API as i cannot whitelist a chrome extension for gmail API / use the existing web app.

To solve this i have put the extension app on a subdomain whitelisted for gmail API and i am loading this domain via an iframe into the chrome extension.

The issue is that the subdomain cannot access the chrome properties inside the iframe:

```
chrome.tabs.query or chrome.runtime.onMessage
```

to enable talk to the content script.

i get the error

```
chrome is not defined
```

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: See [Content script for iframe inside extension popup or background script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725)

Comment: This should work to solve accessing chrome properties in an angular app that is loaded from a subdomain via an iframe injected into the dom with the content script?