# DOMParser is not working in certain websites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, domparser

I'm making a chrome extension.

I'm trying to get some pages' html through the javascript.

I found the code I can use in this site.

Here is the code:

```
fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) { // When the page is loaded convert it to text
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(function (html) { // Initialize the DOM parser
    const parser = new DOMParser();  // Parse the text

    const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    
    console.log(doc);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Failed to fetch page: ', err);
  });
```

Luckily, in most websites this code works well, but in a certain site this doesn't work well.

Here is the link I have problem with: https://ja.dict.naver.com/#/entry/jako/c650d30f378b49dca0ecd6ea85fcc258

I want all nodes' texts but through this code, the "body" part doesn't show up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6H1w.png)

I have searched google, this site and other reference but I can't found the solution and don't know why.

Isn't there way to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not because of DOMParser, but because these sites are using javascript to create the content on the page during normal page load process. It won't run when you fetch the pages. You'll have to use an iframe and a content script inside, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39901725).

Comment: @wOxxOm I have realized I had not known getting nodes from iframe structure. I have investigated a lot of ways to get data from that site and found the api the site provides with thanks to your comment. Thanks a lot.